# StartingNodeUrl - Is it possible to use a Method to set it's value programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, sitemap

From my Content MasterPage I want get the StartingNodeUrl and programmatically set it:

Example of what I'm trying to do:

<'asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" StartingNodeUrl="<%= SomeMethod()%>"    runat="server" />

but that gives the error:

Could not find the sitemap node with URL '<%=SomeMethod() %>'.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do the following in codebehind, for example in the Page_Load():

```
SiteMapDataSource1.StartingNodeUrl = SomeMethod();
```

You cannot use runat=server and <%= %> in one control in an asp.net file.